# Checking several string for null in an if statement

Tags: c#, string, null

Is there a better (nicer) way to write this if statement?

```
if(string1 == null && string2 == null && string3 == null && string4 == null && string5 == null && string6 == null){...}
```

Comment: if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(string1)&& ... -> so you don't only check for null Strings, but also for empty and some containing only spaces

Comment: Do you really need so many separate string variables? Can you not make an array or list of strings and use that instead? It will most likely simplify a lot of other operations as well.

Comment: With the information you've given, no, not really (I guess you can break it over several lines if that helps you), but @JohnWillemse point stands. If you need that many string variables, maybe you need to think about using some different data structure that can encapsulate this logic.

Comment: Personally I'd just write it exactly like that. Although I don't think I'd ever have that many strings to test for nullness without them being in some kind of collection.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. Using list is a good idea, but I also like Tim's solution with null-coalescing operator, so I accepted his answer.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Perhaps using the [null-coalescing operator(`??`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx):

```
if((string1 ?? string2 ?? string3 ?? string4 ?? string5 ?? string6) == null){ ;}
```

If all strings are in a collection you can use Linq:

```
bool allNull = strings.All(s => s == null);
```

Answer (score 15):

You could put all the strings in a list and use

```
if(listOfStrings.All(s=>s==null))
```

At the very least you can put it on multiple lines

```
if(string1 == null 
   && string2 == null 
   && string3 == null 
   && string4 == null 
   && string5 == null 
   && string6 == null)
{...}
```

Comment: i used `||` instead of `&&` to overcome in between null value

Comment: @stom What you you mean by "in between null value"?  If you use `||` instead of `&&` you'll just get at least one value is null instead of all values are null.

Answer (score 14):

If you made a function like this:

```
public static bool AllNull(params string[] strings)
{
    return strings.All(s => s == null);
}
```

Then you could call it like this:

```
if (AllNull(string1, string2, string3, string4, string5, string6))
{
    // ...
}
```

Actually, you could change AllNull() to work with *any* reference type, like this:

```
public static bool AllNull(params object[] objects)
{
    return objects.All(s => s == null);
}
```

Comment: Nice and clean solution!! Though similar to @Tim Schmelter solution, made it way easy by separating it in function and providing a complete example.

Answer (score 6):

```
string[] strs = new string[] { string1, string2, string3 };
if(strs.All(str => string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
{
  //Do Stuff
}
```

Or use `strs.All(str => str == null)` if you don't want to check for empty strings.

Answer (score 3):

Make a IEnumerable of strings (list or array....), then you can use [.All()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx)

```
var myStrings = new List<string>{string1,string2,string3....};
if(myStrings.All(s => s == null))
{
   //Do something
}
```

Comment: Or in a single line ... `if (Enumerable.All(new string[] {str1, str2, str3, str4}, s => s == null))`

Comment: @JimMischel: This creates an additional collection just to shorten an evaluation. Btw, it does not even really shorten it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Yes, it does create an additional collection, as does the answer that you upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't know if it is *nicer* or *better*, or not, you can use **[IEnumerable.Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697.aspx)** method like this;

> Determines whether a sequence contains any elements.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>{"string1","string2","string3", "string4", "string5"};
if(list.Any(n => n == null))
{

}
```

And you can use **[Enumerable.All()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx)** method like;

> Determines whether all elements of a sequence satisfy a condition.

```
if (Enumerable.All(new string[] { string1, string2, string3, string4, string5 }, s => s == null) )
{
       Console.WriteLine("Null");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to check null *or empty*, here is another way without arrays:

```
if (string.Concat(string1, string2, string3, string4, string5).Length == 0)
{
    //all null or empty!
}
```

Comment: Does not check if all are null, the same as with Dennisch's answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the same:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(string1 + string2 + string3 + string4 + string5 + string6)){...}
```

Comment: This will return True if they are empty as well not just null.

Comment: Just use `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` to solve the aforementioned problem and its cake. Love that approach.