# Linq matching variable number of AND conditions

Tags: c#, linq, match

I have a database, which contains a set of rules, which shall be queried for matching ones.

The simplified table contains 5 columns, which contain 4 columns with the pattern strings (let's call them And1..And4) and one for the action (ToDo):

```
A  B  C  D  Todo1
A  -  -  -  Todo2
A  C  -  -  Todo3
C  B  -  -  Todo4
```

Now I have an input pattern with up to 4 conditions, which shall be AND conditions.

The expected result should be s.th. like:

```
(A) -> Todo2
(A,C) -> Todo3, Todo2    // Both rules match the input
(A,B,C) -> Todo3, Todo2
(B,C) -> Todo4 //order of the input should be irrelevant    
(A,B,C,D) -> Todo1, Todo2
```

**Update 29.12.2022:**

Here some sample code, which illustrates the old approach (the first code snippet was incomplete and didn't work), this one does:

```
public List<CombinationRule> GetCombinationRules(string firstElement, List<string> andConditions)
{
    using (var context = _dbContextProvider.GetDbContext())
    {
        var result = new List<CombinationRule>();
        var query = context.CombinationTable
            .Where(x => Match(firstElement, x.ColumnA))

        result.AddRange(SelectItems(query, new List<string> { andConditions[0] }));
        if (andConditions.Count > 1)
        {
            result.AddRange(SelectItems(query, new List<string> { andConditions[1] }));
            result.AddRange(SelectItems(query, new List<string> { andConditions[0], andConditions[1] }));
            result.AddRange(SelectItems(query, new List<string> { andConditions[1], andConditions[0] }));
        }
        if (andConditions.Count > 2)
        {
            result.AddRange(SelectItems(query, new List<string> { andConditions[2] }));
            result.AddRange(SelectItems(query, new List<string> { andConditions[0], andConditions[2] }));
            result.AddRange(SelectItems(query, new List<string> { andConditions[1], andConditions[2] }));
            result.AddRange(SelectItems(query, new List<string> { andConditions[2], andConditions[0] }));
            result.AddRange(SelectItems(query, new List<string> { andConditions[1], andConditions[0] }));
            result.AddRange(SelectItems(query, new List<string> { andConditions[0], andConditions[1], andConditions[2] }));
            result.AddRange(SelectItems(query, new List<string> { andConditions[0], andConditions[2], andConditions[1] }));
            result.AddRange(SelectItems(query, new List<string> { andConditions[1], andConditions[0], andConditions[2] }));
            result.AddRange(SelectItems(query, new List<string> { andConditions[1], andConditions[2], andConditions[0] }));
            result.AddRange(SelectItems(query, new List<string> { andConditions[2], andConditions[0], andConditions[1] }));
            result.AddRange(SelectItems(query, new List<string> { andConditions[2], andConditions[1], andConditions[0] }));
        }
        if (andConditions.Count > 3)
        {
            result.AddRange(SelectItems(query, new List<string> { andConditions[0], andConditions[1], andConditions[3] }));
            result.AddRange(SelectItems(query, new List<string> { andConditions[0], andConditions[3], andConditions[1] }));
            result.AddRange(SelectItems(query, new List<string> { andConditions[0], andConditions[2], andConditions[3] }));
            result.AddRange(SelectItems(query, new List<string> { andConditions[0], andConditions[3], andConditions[2] }));
            result.AddRange(SelectItems(query, new List<string> { andConditions[1], andConditions[0], andConditions[3] }));
            result.AddRange(SelectItems(query, new List<string> { andConditions[1], andConditions[3], andConditions[0] }));
            result.AddRange(SelectItems(query, new List<string> { andConditions[1], andConditions[2], andConditions[3] }));
            result.AddRange(SelectItems(query, new List<string> { andConditions[1], andConditions[3], andConditions[2] }));
            result.AddRange(SelectItems(query, new List<string> { andConditions[2], andConditions[0], andConditions[3] }));
            result.AddRange(SelectItems(query, new List<string> { andConditions[2], andConditions[3], andConditions[0] }));
            result.AddRange(SelectItems(query, new List<string> { andConditions[2], andConditions[1], andConditions[3] }));
            result.AddRange(SelectItems(query, new List<string> { andConditions[2], andConditions[3], andConditions[1] }));
            result.AddRange(SelectItems(query, new List<string> { andConditions[3], andConditions[0], andConditions[1] }));
            result.AddRange(SelectItems(query, new List<string> { andConditions[3], andConditions[1], andConditions[0] }));
            result.AddRange(SelectItems(query, new List<string> { andConditions[3], andConditions[0], andConditions[2] }));
            result.AddRange(SelectItems(query, new List<string> { andConditions[3], andConditions[2], andConditions[0] }));
            result.AddRange(SelectItems(query, new List<string> { andConditions[3], andConditions[1], andConditions[2] }));
            result.AddRange(SelectItems(query, new List<string> { andConditions[3], andConditions[2], andConditions[1] }));
        }

        return result.Distinct().ToList();
    }
}
```

The method uses 2 helpers, **Match** and **SelectItems**. Match is a special string matching, based on special business logic rules. SelectItems selects the rules for 1, 2 or 3 conditions. SelectItems is implemented as follows:

```
private List<CombinationRule> SelectItems(IQueryable<CombinationTable> query,
                                                             List<string> andOrderNumbers)
    {
        switch(andOrderNumbers.Count)
        {
            case 1:
                query = query.Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.And2OrderNumber) &&
                                     string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.And3OrderNumber))
                         .Where(x => Match(andOrderNumbers[0], x.And1OrderNumber));
                break;
            case 2:
                query = query.Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.And3OrderNumber))
                                             .Where(x => Match(andOrderNumbers[0], x.And1OrderNumber) &&
                                                         Match(andOrderNumbers[1], x.And2OrderNumber));
                break;
            case 3:
                query = query.Where(x => Match(andOrderNumbers[0], x.And1OrderNumber) &&
                                       Match(andOrderNumbers[1], x.And2OrderNumber) &&
                                       Match(andOrderNumbers[2], x.And3OrderNumber));
                break;
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        var result = query.Select(x => new CombinationRule(x.PrimaryOrderNumber,                                                    
                                                new List<string> { x.And1OrderNumber, x.And2OrderNumber, x.And3OrderNumber },
                                                x.ToDo))
                .Distinct()
                .ToList();

        return result;
    }
```

The approach depended on manual typing of all possible variations of the 4 condition elements. It can be boiled down to building all the possible variations. I found a great article at CodeProject, which explains the difference between variations, permutations and combinations ([Variations, Combinations, Permutations](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26050/Permutations-Combinations-and-Variations-using-C-G))

Variations of {A B C} choose 2, expected result:

```
{A B}, {A C}, {B A}, {B C}, {C A}, {C B}
```

After getting to the point of the problem, the question, how to get rid of the ugly code, can be answered easily. It was an easy thing to create the variations by method and then throwing them into the SelectItems method.

Comment: Normally you set up each condition as a power of two like A = 1, B = 2, C = 3, D = 4.  Then you can test for Todo1 = 15 (OR 1 OR 2 OR 4 OR 8).

Comment: What is the actual question? How to design the DB? How to query the DB? How to materialize the query to a CLR object? What?

Comment: have you looked at dynamic linq?

Comment: I don't think your question is clear enough. I am not getting what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @MetroSmurf: The DB is already designed. I think it's good as it is. My problem is the code, Looks ugly and inefficient.

Comment: @WhatsThePoint: Dynamic Linq sounds interesting. But introduces an additional Nuget package..

Comment: You can build-up an `IQueryable<T>` by re-assigning and appending new `.Where()` steps. You don't need DynamicLinq (and DynamicLinq is an anti-pattern, in my book).

Comment: @mrAtari without adding anything extra you could clean up the `isnullorempy`s with something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14982662/7147233) but them IMO you lose some readability

Comment: Tip: don't use `.AsNoTracking();` unless you **absolutely** know that you need it, because it breaks EF's ability to perform many types of Joins, `Include` and `GroupBy` operations.

Comment: What is your `Match` function? And you say the conditions are `AND` but you're using the `||` (OR) operator...

Comment: `x.And3` <-- What is `x` and what are these `And1`, `And2`, etc properties? Why is your _table_ named `MyDB`? (Tables aren't databases...). That looks like a database designed by someone who doesn't know what they're doing....

Comment: @Dai I'd suspect `MyDB` is just what he has anonymised his code with

Answer (score 0):

So here is the function, which can build the VARIATIONS of k elements choosing n  elements:

```
static void GenerateVariationsNoRepetitions(int[] kArray, int[] nArray, int index, List<List<int>> result)
{
    if (index >= kArray.Length)
    {
        result.Add(kArray.ToList());
        return;
    }
    for (int i = index; i < nArray.Length; i++)
    {
        kArray[index] = nArray[i];
        Swap(ref nArray[i], ref nArray[index]);
        GenerateVariationsNoRepetitions(kArray, nArray, index + 1, result);
        Swap(ref nArray[i], ref nArray[index]);
    }
}
private static void Swap<T>(ref T v1, ref T v2)
{
    T old = v1;
    v1 = v2;
    v2 = old;
}
```

With that in mind, the **GetCombinationRules** method can be rewritten smaller and shorter:

```
public List<CombinationRule> GetCombinationRules(string firstElement, List<string> andConditions)
{
    using (var context = _dbContextProvider.GetDbContext())
    {
        var result = new List<CombinationRule>();
        var query = context.CombinationTable.AsNoTracking()
            .Where(x => Match(firstElement, x.ColumnA));

        for (int i=0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            int[] kArr = new int[i+1];
            int[] nArr = Enumerable.Range(0, andConditions.Count).ToArray();
            var combinations = new List<List<int>>();

            GenerateVariationsNoRepetitions(kArr, nArr, 0, combinations);
            foreach (var combi in combinations)
            {
                var list = new List<string>();
                foreach (int c in combi)
                {
                    list.Add(andConditions[c]);
                }
                result.AddRange(SelectItems(query, list));
            }
        }

        return result.Distinct().ToList();
    }
}
```

I am sure, this is not the shortest and most elegant implementation, but it has good readability and is easily extendable.

By the way, even in the first implementation, I made a small rearrangement (including a minor redefenition of the data format), to improve performance. You remember, I needed variations out of 4 elements, but the implementation contains one primary element and variations out of 3 elements. This improves performance drastically, since the first query for the primary element (which has to be always of Type A, reduces the initial result from roughly 10k elements to below 10 and also reduces the number of the rest variations. This way the performance is roughly acceptable.